# SQLite adding row to table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to add members to a membership table. My SQLite database can already successfully add rows to other tables such as my book table and inventory table. For some reason, it won't add a new Member to the table, which puzzles me because I'm seemingly just copying the same structure as the insert statements that I used successfully add to the other tables. What might be going wrong here?

**MembershipAdapter**

```
public void insertEntry(String FIRSTNAME, String LASTNAME, String BIRTHDAY,
        String MEMBER_ID, String EMAIL, int CHECKOUT_COUNT, int KARMA_PTS,
        String NOTES)
{
   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
   if(FIRSTNAME.equals(null))
       newValues.put("FIRST_NAME", "");
   else
        newValues.put("FIRST_NAME", FIRSTNAME);
   if(LASTNAME.equals(null))
       newValues.put("LAST_NAME", "");
   else
       newValues.put("LAST_NAME", LASTNAME);
   if(BIRTHDAY.equals(null))
        newValues.put("BIRTHDAY", "");
   else
       newValues.put("BIRTHDAY", BIRTHDAY);
   if(MEMBER_ID.equals(null))
        newValues.put("MEMBER_ID", "");
   else
       newValues.put("MEMBER_ID", MEMBER_ID);
   if(EMAIL.equals(null))
        newValues.put("EMAIL", "");
   else
       newValues.put("EMAIL", EMAIL);
   if(CHECKOUT_COUNT==0)
        newValues.put("CHECKOUT_COUNT", 0);
   else
       newValues.put("CHECKOUT_COUNT", CHECKOUT_COUNT);
   if(KARMA_PTS==0)
        newValues.put("KARMA_PTS", 0);
   else
       newValues.put("KARMA_PTS", KARMA_PTS);
   if(NOTES.equals(null))
        newValues.put("NOTES", "");
   else
       newValues.put("NOTES", NOTES);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("MEMBERSHIP", null, newValues);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Member Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public int countMembers()
    {
        int count = 0;
        String query = "select * from MEMBERSHIP";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // title Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return 0;
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
```

**MemberAddScreen**

```
MembershipAdapter=new MembershipAdapter(this);
    MembershipAdapter=MembershipAdapter.open();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String userName = intent.getExtras().getString("username");

    buttonMemberAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMemberAdd);
        buttonMemberAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
              String firstName = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
              String lastName = inputLastName.getText().toString();
              String birthday = inputBirthday.getText().toString();
              String memberId = inputMemberId.getText().toString();
              String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
              String notes = inputNotes.getText().toString();

              MembershipAdapter.insertEntry(firstName, lastName, birthday, memberId, email, 0, 0, notes);
              System.out.println("Count Members: "+MembershipAdapter.countMembers());
              System.out.println(MembershipAdapter.getAll()[MembershipAdapter.countMembers()-1][0]);
              Toast.makeText(MemberAddScreen.this, "Member Successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i=new Intent(MemberAddScreen.this,ManageMemberScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("username",userName);
                startActivity(i);
          }
      });
```

After clicking the buttonMemberAdd, my log shows that the number of rows in the table is still zero.

```
05-17 01:56:55.660: I/System.out(2995): Count Members: 0
```

Comment: Does it show toast you have placed after successful insertion ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It immediately crashes because of an index out of bounds error.

Comment: Try use a different table name to test. I could be wrong but sometimes there are reserved names that you cant use as table names.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case here, because naming with a reserved name would throw an exception much earlier.

Comment: have you initialized `MembershipAdapter` ?

Comment: Yes. I believe I have successfully initialized MembershipAdapter.

Comment: can u please post that code ? and also specify the code of MembershipAdapter.countMembers(), so that it can help to find whats going wrong.

Comment: ok I added those items.

Comment: @erad `db.insert` will return you row id of newly inserted record. first of all, check its value in log and let me know.

Comment: Where is your table creation?  When i've had problems like this, it has always been a problem with a spelling error difference between the table creation and my insert call.  For example, I would have initially called the field CHEKCOUT_COUNT instead lf CHECKOUT_COUNT.

Comment: @Dig the db.insert statement returns -1. So I guess there was an error. I'm still trying to pinpoint the location of the error though.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help. It turns out that the error was in my table. I added two columns to my original table without properly altering the table structure. As a quick fix, I just uninstalled the app and installed a new version which created a brand new table.